# How to deploy alx file on BB device using OTA approach?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have my projects alx file, where-in all required cod files name is listed. I want to deploy/ install this proj onto BB device using OTA approcach. How do i do this ?

And i also have an alx file listing all library cod files name. I wanna deploy this as well before i deploy my proj alx, using OTA approach.

Pls tell me, how to do this ?

Thanks,
Swapna

Comment: in OTA method, you can install the app using the .COD file.

Answer (score 2):

alx file is only for BES / Desktop Manager installs. To deploy Over The Air you need the sibling cod files and the jad file.

In eclipse plugin, you can find the jad file and the sibling cods inside the `deliverables\Web` folder. Make sure you have signed them first. Then, upload the files to the web. The OTA install is launched when the published jad file URL is typed in the BlackBerry browser.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. how do i knw, published jad file URL for my project? And can i edit the jad file and still be able to upload it ?

Comment: You need to publish the files in a web server, but this is not an automated process, you need to upload the files the same way you would do with a web page. And about the jad file, yes you can edit it.